# ActionBarSherlock - How to set the padding of each actionbar's icon?

Tags: android, icons, padding, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

How can I make the icons of the actionbar **using ActionBarSherlock** closer or further away from each other? Something like `android:layout_marginLeft`or `android:paddingRight`?

If I just add the icons on the actionbar they are further away compare to the screenshot of Soundhound below:

[image: SoundHound]

my `themes.xml`:

```
<style name="Theme.AstraTheme_Purple" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.AstraTheme_Purple.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.AstraTheme_Purple.ActionBar</item>

    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AstraTheme_Purple.ActionButton</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/Widget.AstraTheme_Purple.ActionButton</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.AstraTheme_Purple.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/purple_bar</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/purple_bar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.AstraTheme_Purple.ActionButton" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:minWidth">50dip</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:minWidth">32dip</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dip</item>
</style>
```

The default value of `android:minWidth` for the `ActionBar` buttons is `56dip`.
Don't forget to set `@style/AppTheme` as the `Activity`'s theme.

Comment: I tried including actionButtonStyle on my existing theme, and i even made a new theme to check it out (and applied it via Manifest and via setTheme in the onCreate method), but nothing changed. Am i missing something?

I edited the question with my themes.xml  (i included item name="android:actionButtonStyle", no idea if it's needed or not). Please check it out

Comment: weird. I tried making a new project and setting a new theme there. I even re-downloaded ABS just in case something was wrong with the library (since i was on 4.0.1 and now its 4.1), but still nothing.
I tried running on real devices, and emulators and nothing changes... Maybe its just my end and i need to change something else apart from the stuff I wrote above... Anyway, thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: @matthias How about action button icon size setting? is it possible too?

Comment: I'm not sure. But why not include files with the right dimensions?

Comment: It works. But it works only for level 11 and above.If that is the case why I should use ActionbarSherlock?

Comment: @bagusflyer: If you copy the styles from above, it will also work for api <11 with ActionBarSherlock. ABS is only for using action bar on api <11.

Comment: <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item> requires api 11

Comment: @J. Kowalski: That is why there is the additional `<item name="actionButtonStyle">` for lower than API 11. What you are referring to is only a lint warning. To be absolutely correct, you would have to create a `res-v11/styles.xml` with attributes like `android:actionButtonStyle`. But you can also ignore the lint warning because Android also ignores such attributes on older APIs.