# Padding menu items in action bar sherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm having action bar which **Title Name**, **Search** and **Action Overflow** menu item, though i'm using ActionBarSherlock library for this. I want to remove padding for search and Action Overflow menu item in action bar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check this link:

[ActionBarSherlock - How to set the padding of each actionbar's icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759282/actionbarsherlock-how-to-set-the-padding-of-each-actionbars-icon#answers-header)

The idea is to create a new theme which has a parent theme as **Theme.Sherlock**

and lower **actionButtonStyle** `minWidth` attribute

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:minWidth">28dip</item>
</style>
```

and apply this theme to your Activity in the manifest.