# Problems with ActionOverflow and HoloEverywhere/ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-menu, android-holo-everywhere

**I'm probably going to get flamed for this, but I have my reasons.

I'm making app has an option to switch between 3 themes (Holo Dark, Holo Light, and Holo Light with Dark ActionBar). Because of certain reasons, I used [>>this<<](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568024/1625043) hack to make ActionOverflow work with devices with hard menu keys using ActionBarSherlock 4.2. The problem is that whenever I have the theme set to Holo Dark or Holo Light, the height of the menu items is a rather large (about 48dp), but whenever I have it set to Holo Light with Dark Actionbar, the height of the menu items is normal (whatever normal is).
Anyone have any ideas what's making the menuitems act strange?
I've tried checking in Styles, but I'm not sure where the problem is originating from.
If you need more info, just ask :D

[image: Holo Dark] [image: Holo Light with Dark Actionbar] [image: Holo Light]

Comment: Add screenshots and be more precise about what you exactly want or don't want. 48 dp is the standard action bar size by the way.

Comment: @Snicolas added screenshots for all three themes

Comment: Did you try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720494/padding-menu-items-in-action-bar-sherlock

Comment: @Snicolas I'm talking about the listitems in the menu. I don't think I saw anything in that styles.xml about changing the minHeight of the listitem or why it's this big only on holo dark and holo light

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!
I gave up soon after I posted this question, but I came back to it, played around with the ABS library, and found out the answer!
What I did was add:

```
<item name="dropdownListPreferredItemHeight">48dp</item>
```

to my styles.xml within:

```
<style name="ThemeDark" parent="Holo.Theme"></style>
```

I did this to both Dark and Light themes and it's working just fine! :D