# Spacing between overflow icon and action items in ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am using ActionBarSherlock(ABS) in my project, the overflow icon takes too much margin to the left from the action items. I have the latest library of ABS in my project. You can see the screenshot below of the mentioned problem.

[image: sherlock action bar jelly bean]

The mobile is running on JellyBean version. How can i reduce the space between the overflow icon and action items?

**UPDATE**

I have tried changing the action items attributes , by applying the custom theme

```
<style name="DelightActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton">
        <!--  <item name="android:background">?attr/actionBarItemBackground</item> -->
        <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">?attr/actionBarSize</item>

        <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:scaleType">center</item>
    </style>
```

only background attribute takes effect on the devices which doesn't have menu button. i played with the attributes changing the margins and padding, nothing seems to have an effect. Is there a way to control these attributes for action items?

Comment: i have changed the minWidth attribute, but it only shows changes in pre ICS, and fails to reflect any change in ICS+ phones.

Comment: Did you add `android:actionButtonStyle` as well as `actionButtonStyle`? The former controls ICS+.

Answer (score 6):

If you really need to change it, here is how to reduce the width of the overflow button:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyOverflowButton</item>
</style>

<style name="MyOverflowButton" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:minWidth">32dip</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dip</item>
</style>
```

Comment: oh that `android:padding` helped me a lot on samsung s3 and s4 as `android:paddingLeft` and `android:paddingRight` weren't working.

Answer (score 2):

Your action buttons are too small. They should not be smaller than 48dp. If this must be done (it shouldn't), you can override the `actionButtonStyle` `android:minWidth` attribute:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10808259/377260

Be sure to also include `android:actionButtonStyle`.

Comment: not working on devices 4.0 +, atleast on the ones which doesn't have menu button.

Comment: You're right, this doesn't make the Overflow button smaller. That's probably because it really, really shouldn't be smaller that 48dp wide. I'll look into whether this is possible, though.