# Is there a way to remove icon margin in ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, action

I have my navigation button on my action bar, but what I want is to keep it together. In image below you can have a better idea what I'm talking

[image]

I have my navigation button on my action bar, and want is to keep it together. In image below you can have a better idea what I'm talking.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/TargetBarAction</item>        
</style>

<style name="TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="TextColorActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="TargetBarAction" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/header</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@style/TextColorActionBar</item>
</style>
```

How can I remove the margin? Even if I increase image's size, it keeps with the margin

Comment: You want the two navigation buttons to be together, right? Show us your action bar XML layout.

Comment: Also make sure the margin doesn't belong to the button images (as a transparent margin maybe).

Comment: Please try http://stackoverflow.com/a/10808259.