# values-sw600dp won't work

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I have the following values folders (in addition to the default one): `values-sw400dp`, `values-sw600dp`. Since I need so remove spacing between my actionBar icons I used a style:

```
     <style name="ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
</style>
```

and just copied styles.xml into all of the values folders. On SGS2 i9100 running 4.1.1 it works fine, but on a PocketBook tablet (running same android version) the spacing seems to be the default one. The following method returns 600:

```
    public static int getScreenWidth(Activity a) {

    Display display = a.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

    float density = a.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float dpWidth = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;

    return (int) dpWidth;

}
```

So the question is: why does the device ignore styles from values-sw600dp folder?

**UPDATE**  I just added windowBackground item to styles in values-sw600dp. It is displayed correctly. But why is the padding for the actionBar ignored? Setting negative padding does not change anything

Comment: Try adding `<item name="android:paddingStart">0dip</item>` and `<item name="android:paddingEnd">0dip</item>` to `ActionBarTabStyle`.

Comment: guys I use a normal ActionBar and not Sherlock. And the padding only has no effect on tablets. paddingStart and paddingEnd are not acceptable attributes for TabView

Comment: Do you need padding for icons or for tabs?

Comment: My actionBar uses Tabs (icons and not text), for navigation and I need to reduce spacing between them. The style I posted works fine on phones but not tablets

Comment: `Widget.ActionBar.TabView` is the parent of `Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView` which defines `paddingStart` and `paddingEnd` = 16dp.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to set paddings to your actionbar icons:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:minWidth">32dip</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dip</item>
</style>
```

The default value of android:minWidth for the ActionBar buttons is 56dip. Don't forget to set @style/AppTheme as the Activity's theme.

[[ActionBarSherlock - How to set the padding of each actionbar's icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759282/actionbarsherlock-how-to-set-the-padding-of-each-actionbars-icon][1])

Source: [ActionBarSherlock - How to set the padding of each actionbar's icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759282/actionbarsherlock-how-to-set-the-padding-of-each-actionbars-icon)

Comment: I dont use Sherlock but a normal ActionBar. My minSDK is 11

Comment: should I change it in the style overriding Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView ?