# How do I change the appcompat actionbar default padding of top and bottom by using xml theme?

Tags: android, android-layout

how to change the top and bottom padding or margin of the action bar icon or logo space by using XML theme?

```
<style name="Theme.Whycheck" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_whycheck</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Whycheck</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_whycheck</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_whycheck</item>

            <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Whycheck.Widget</item>

</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Whycheck" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_whycheck</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_whycheck</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_whycheck</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Whycheck" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_whycheck</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.Whycheck.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
</style>
```

Provided my styles.

Comment: I have no idea how to do...someone please help me...and sorry, my english is poor..

Answer (score 4):

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10808259/1025599) didn't work for me, here's how I solved it:

Add this to your `<application>` tag in your manifest

```
android:logo="@drawable/logo"
```

*Note: your `logo` and `icon` are not the same thing!*

Then create `drawable/logo.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/actual_logo_or_icon_image"
        android:left="30dp"/> <!-- add other margins here -->
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Hi Nachi, It's only working on left and right...but cannot reduce the top/bottom layout margin :)

Answer (score 0):

If you using Action Bar Sherlock, check this answer: [Padding menu items in action bar sherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10808259/2702648)

Also, you can write something like that for home icon:

```
ImageView im = ( ImageView ) findViewById ( android.R.id.home );
im.setPadding ( left, top, right, bottom );
```

Comment: Hi, Volodmyr...I am using appcompat