# How to add Sliding Menu button below the Top of screen?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I am using ActionBarSherLock and SlidingMenu liberary to implement sliding menu.
But the problem is I want to add this sliding menu button leaving some space from top. I want the whole actionbar and this button should leave some space above. Is this Possible ? If yes How ?

Comment: Dunno what you're asking. Please provide an code example or a screenshot or anything to better grasp what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/a8pe6t  have a look at this pic @m02ph3u5

Comment: plz take a look at this http://prntscr.com/a8pe6t

Comment: What's wrong with *margin/padding*? :)

Comment: this is sliding bar button and I am using actionbarsherlock.
It puts the button on upper left corner

Comment: Do you need more space between the menu button and "Call"? Or what's the issue? Please be more specific.

Comment: this is what I have implemented. I want this navigation button to leave some space in the Top http://prntscr.com/a8pnxm

Comment: Haven't worked with actionbarsherlock so far. If you used a `Toolbar` you could freely position it. You should try to edit your theme, also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759282/actionbarsherlock-how-to-set-the-padding-of-each-actionbars-icon