# Add margin for element in Toolbar

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have created a custom `Toolbar`, but all of the elements in it have no methods of moving. I just want to replace Fenix icon in left side on the toolbar (maybe with help of margins).

Here's my XML menu code:

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/risensteam_button"
    android:title="@string/main"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_unnamed"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/news_button"
    android:icon="@drawable/news_icon"
    android:title="@string/main"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/ongoing_button"
    android:icon="@drawable/ongoing_icon"
    android:title="@string/ongoing"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/base_button"
    android:icon="@drawable/base_icon"
    android:title="@string/base"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/manga_button"
    android:icon="@drawable/manga_icon"
    android:title="@string/manga"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/novels_button"
    android:icon="@drawable/novels_icon"
    android:title="@string/novels"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Replace with what? With new icon? Also having this much icons in `Toolbar`  with `showAsAction` on `always` is not a god practice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase padding or margin between menu item icon and title in app toolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39843904/how-to-increase-padding-or-margin-between-menu-item-icon-and-title-in-app-toolba)

Answer (score 0):

you can also add custom toolbar not use action menu add as image in toolbar as per your requirement