# Android menu.xml icon size issue with padding

Tags: android

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:minWidth">20dip</item>
    <item name="android:padding">20dip</item>
</style>
```

i am using this code for adding padding or space between item of menu.xml but issue is that if i added padding then icon size reducing. How can i keep same size of icon with spacing between them and is there any way to set margin between
menu items?

Comment: Check the following link :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39900234/2919483

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it will be help you

```
 <style name="MenuIconStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">@dimen/padding_small</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MenuIconStyle</item>
    </style>
```